# Creating a single xml object from multiple xml snippets in a pandas series

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have a series in my dataframe as follows

```
0     <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® USB 2.0 Hard D...
1     <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® 2.4GHz 4 Keys ...
2     <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® 802.11n/g/b 15...
3     <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® Wireless Bluet...
4     <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® Laptop Sleeve ...
5     <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® Mini DisplayPo...
6     <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® USB 3.0 Female...
7     <Product><Name>Kalyan  1.8m Black Superspeed D...
8     <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® Laptop Sleeve ...
9     <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® Laptop Sleeve ...
10    <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® Laptop Sleeve ...
```

I am trying to bring all these xml snippet into a single xml object like follows

```
<Request>
   <Products>
       <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® USB 2.0 Hard D...</Product>
       <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® 2.4GHz 4 Keys ...</Product>
       ....
       ....
       <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® Laptop Sleeve ...</Product>
       <Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® Laptop Sleeve ...</Product>
   </Products>
</Request>
```

When i convert the values of this series into a list so that i can use 'join' function to later collate them using .tolist() as follows

```
product_list = df['Product'].tolist()
```

The non ascii characters come converted in the list.
Like first element

```
<Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans® USB 2.0 Hard D...
```

Is coming like

```
u'<Product><Name>Kalyan Bluelans\xae USB 2.0 Hard D...
```

How do i ensure no ascii decoding occurs and the required output xml is containing the non ascii characters.

Comment: using dicttoxml i converted a dictonary into xml snippet

Comment: The Series is nothing but column 'Product' of the dataframe
df['Product']

Comment: The dataframe is basically loaded from a excel file which is passed after processing. We have to batch upload these products using an post api call for which we have to create the mentioned xml output before sending it along with the request. Hence i have to parse these unicode and convert them to xml objects and collate them